# How to interrupt an ajax request when opening a new webpage?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a few menu items on the left side of the screen, each opens a new page on the site. On one of the pages there is an async ajax call to python that successfully returns a bunch of data.

However, when I open this page and quickly click on another menu item to open another page without waiting for the ajax request to finish, I receive an [Object object] error.

```
postData = {"userid":userid, "current":dict_current, "step":dict_step};

$.ajax({
    url: "/cgi-bin/get_dictionary.py",
    type: "post",
    datatype:"json",
    async : true,
    data: {postData},
    success: function(response){
        //parse json
        var json = $.parseJSON(response);
    } 
})
.fail(function(err) {
    alert("error" + err); //[Object object]
});
```

So I guess, I should somehow abort the request when I open a new page, but how do I access that request?

What is the best thing to do here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a variable name for your ajax request.
define variable first.

```
var ajaxreq;
```

then use that variable for your ajax request:

```
ajaxreq = $.ajax(...);
```

and abort that ajax on page unload:

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
  ajaxreq.abort();
});
```

Comment: unload did not work, but `window.onbeforeunload = function() {ajaxreq.abort();}; did`. Thanks! But honestly the easiest solution is to don't alert the error. Question is if it's okay when it comes to performance